# Linker error when implementing NSObject protocol while using enums?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, linker, linker-errors

Here is a distilled version of the code I am having trouble with in Swift:

```
enum E {
  case C
}

class Test: NSObject {
  var v: E = .C
}
```

When I attempt to build, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TWvdvC8TestTest4Test1vOS_1E", referenced from:
      __TFC8TestTest4Testm1vOS_1E in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To reproduce this, simply make a new Swift project and paste the above code right into "AppDelegate.swift". Alternatively, make a new file and stick it in there instead!

Am I missing something obvious or is this yet another Swift bug? I did try deleting all derived data and other forms of voodoo magic.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a couple things when trying this:

1. In the current non-beta version of Xcode, I see the error you're referring to (almost certainly a Swift bug). However, if I add an extra value to the enum (`case C,D`), it compiles just fine
2. I couldn't reproduce the crash in the latest Xcode beta (Version 6.3 (6D520o)), which leads me to believe that the bug has been fixed in Swift 1.2

Comment: Ah, correct! I thought I _was_ using 1.2, but it seems I had accidentally launched the stable version of Xcode instead. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the compiler removes the enum if there is only one case?

I can reproduce your issue, it disappears when I add a second case :

```
enum E {
  case C,D
}

class Test: NSObject {
   var v : E = .C
}
```